# Issues getting the Facebook PHP SDK to work on my application

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk

I was making a facebook application in which i have to show news feeds of the user who is using it. I am using graph API to do this. The problem is that its not getting me feeds.
I used it to show friends like this:

```
$friends = $facebook->api('/me/friends');
```

and it is working fine.

For news feeds i use this:

```
$feeds   = $facebook->api('/me/home');
```

it shows me an error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught IDInvalidException: Invalid id: 0 thrown in 
/home/content/58/6774358/html/test/src/facebook.php on line 560
```

when i try to get Profile feed (Wall) by using this:

```
$feeds   = $facebook->api('/me/feed');
```

it shows me an empty array.

These API calls are showing me results in the graph API page but don't know why not working in my application.Can any one help me please..
My full code is as follows

```
require_once 'src/facebook.php';
```

// Create our Application instance.
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId' => 'xxxxx',
  'secret' => 'xxxxx',
  'cookie' => true,
));

```
$session = $facebook->getSession();
    $fbme = null;
// Session based graph API call.
if (!empty($session)){
    $fbme = $facebook->api('/me');
}
if ($fbme) {
     $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();
     echo '<a href="'.$logoutUrl.'">Logout</a>';
}else{
    $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl();
     echo '<a href="'.$loginUrl.'">Logout</a>';
}
$friends = $facebook->api('/me/friends?access_token='.$session["access_token"]);
$feeds   = $facebook->api('/me/feed?access_token='.$session["access_token"]); 
print('<pre>Herere:');print_r($feeds);die;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you ask for the [read_stream permission](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/) during authentication?

What type of [Authentication](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/) / "Allow" process did you go through?

JavaScript SDK? Facebook PHP SDK? XFBML Login Button?

**EDIT**- Here are helpful link that will get you started up:

[Facebook PHP SDK](https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk)

[Authentication Process](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/)

[Building Apps on Facebook.com](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/canvas/)

These are all official docs in Facebook and github.

---

**EDIT**: Follow this step by step:

From your original code, look for:

```
$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl();
```

Change it to:

```
$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array('req_perms'=>'read_stream'));
```

Uninstall your application first from your account:

```
http://www.facebook.com/settings/?tab=applications
```

Then try it again to show new **Allow** pop-up

---

**EDIT**:

It's also about the arrangement of code in the if statements. Use this code:

```
<?php
require_once 'src/facebook.php';
$session = $facebook->getSession();
$fbme = null;

if($session){
    $fbme = $facebook->api('/me');
    $friends = $facebook->api('/me/friends');
    $feeds = $facebook->api('/me/feed'); 
    $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();
    echo '<a href="'.$logoutUrl.'">Logout</a>';
    echo "<pre>".print_r($feeds,TRUE)."</pre>";
}else{
    $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array('req_perms'=>'read_stream','canvas'=>1,'fbconnect'=>0));
    echo '<script> top.location.href="'.$loginUrl.'"; </script>>';
}
```

Uninstall your app again from

```
http://www.facebook.com/settings/?tab=applications
```

and re-open the application

Comment: im using Facebook PHP SDK i used the link                http://thinkdiff.net/facebook/php-sdk-graph-api-base-facebook-connect-tutorial/
My code is as follows:

require_once 'src/facebook.php';

// Create our Application instance.
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId' => 'xxxxxxxx',
  'secret' => 'xxxxxxxx',
  'cookie' => true,
)); 
 $friends = $facebook->api('/me/friends');
 $feeds  = $facebook->api('/me/feed'); 
print('<pre>Herere:');print_r($feeds);die;

Comment: can you edit your question an re-post this code in full? you did not include the actual authentication script which usually has getLoginUrl(), top.href.location, redirection and the like.

Comment: Please look at the quesiton now
@dragonjet

Comment: If this is your full code, I'm not sure how you managed to even get /me/friends. You basically need an if($facebook->getSession()) somewhere in the code and redirect to getLoginUrl(), you don't have those?

Comment: I modified the code and re posted it in the question please look now.Also this is my first time with facebook apps so can you give me the link to any good basic tutorial to setup a facebook app?I have noticed that the url does not work for any other Facebook ID except mine it shows the friends for my id only which i used to create this app.My app url is http://apps.facebook.com/test_this_new_app/ @dragonjet

Comment: I edited my answer above, I added links and code, check it now.

Comment: Thanx for your comments dragonjet but it still dont fetch my my feeds.@dragonjet

Comment: no error messages..the feeds array(echo "<pre>".print_r($feed,TRUE)."</pre>";) is empty.@dragonjet

Comment: whenever i try to run my previous code(written in the orignal question above) from another Facebook account it shows me this error


Fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException: An active access token must be used to query information about the current user. thrown in /home/content/58/6774358/html/test/src/facebook.php on line 560

i dont know why the code i have written first is working for me only@dragonjet

Comment: cant figure out why it shows me friends for my facebook id and shows this error atal error: Uncaught OAuthException: An active access token must be used to query information about the current user. thrown in /home/content/58/6774358/html/test/src/facebook.php on line 560 for another facebook id@dragonjet

Comment: i went to the URL http://www.facebook.com/settings/?tab=applications
 and then removed the application from there.now it doesnt shows me my friends but and this error Fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException: An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.Do you mean i have to reconfigure it to show ALLOW popup?from where do we enable this ALLOW popup @dragonjet

Comment: oh sorry, it is not pop-up. you should see a "Login" link that will redirect the whole page to the allow dialog. oh and don't put the acccess_token inside the api(). The SDK will handle it for you. Just put api("/me/friends");

Comment: it is showing me the Login button.But below that login button it is showing me this error 
Fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException: An active access token must be used to query information about the current user. thrown in /home/content/58/6774358/html/test/src/facebook.php on line 560
And on clicking LOGIN nothing happens.@dragonje

Comment: it doesnt takes me to the ALLOW dialog @dragonjet

Comment: its also about the arrangement of your codes inside the if statements, I edited my answer, use that code and uninstall you app again.

Comment: Thats ok..but the LOGIN does not take me to anywhere.it doesnt shows any dialogue box.I visited this link http://www.facebook.com/settings/?tab=applications and clicked on REMOVE APP to remove the app from my account.is that what you mean by uninstall@dragonjet

Comment: Yes that's what I meant by "Remove App". If you meant doesn't take you anywhere, maybe it's because direct <a href> doesn't work on iframe apps. You might need to redirect automatically, and not show a Login Link. I edited the answer again, please check.

Comment: I have tried this too earlier as suggested by @Jim Rubenstein.It doesnt helps me too it takes me to the page http://www.facebook.com/developers/login_error.php?app_id=113439898741047&connect=1&type=connect and there nothing happenes.I guess Jim Rubenstein was right that facebook is having issues with the apps.What do you say?Thankx for your time anyways@dragonjet

Comment: Oh, as the URL suggests, you are recognized as a facebook connect site, instead of an app in the facebook iframe canvas. I have customized the code in my answer further. Try it and re-do the steps :)

Comment: Yes you really helped me @dragonjet thank you..can you please explain it to me in some detail.thanx

Comment: Ok I'll explain the whole thing, so you might wanna look at the code while reading. First, we check if session exists or not. All codes must be put inside this if-else. If session exists, do your API thing. In the else clause, it means session does not exist and you should redirect the user to the login/allow page. The login URL us tricky, you should specify there everything you want like permissions, canvas etc. Remember you need to uninstall before testing because we are dealing with authentication. Once you're logged in correctly and successfully doing API calls, no need to do this anymore.

Comment: LOL @dragonjet.I knew what the code means Thank you for that but i wanted to know about facebook connect site and app in the facebook iframe canvas.Thanks for your explanation any how

Comment: OH sorry about that XD look at the documentation links above I included in the answer :)

Answer (score 2):

The Facebook PHP SDK should handle your access token for you, you don't need to append it to your graph API endpoint in you `Facebook::api()` call.

As @dragonjet pointed out, you need to request the [read_stream](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/) extended permission from your FB User in order to get access to their feed.  Though, the exception you pasted doesn't really match that kind of problem, and your request to `/me/home` doesn't throw a similar exception (or one about not having access).

I still think this is a permissions issue, so start here for trying to fix it.  Here's an example of how to request the appropriate permission.

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId' => FB_APP_ID, //put your FB APP ID here
    'secret' => FB_APP_SECRET, //put your FB APP SECRET KEY here
    'cookie' => true
));

$session = $facebook->getSession();

if ($session)
{
    //check to see if we have friends_birthday permission
    $perms = $facebook->api('/me/permissions');
}

 //we do this to see if the user is logged & installed
if (empty($session) || empty($perms['read_stream']))
{
    //get url to oauth endpoint for install/login
    $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
        //put the URL to this page, relative to the FB canvas
        //(apps.facebook.com) here vvv
        'next' => 'http://apps.facebook.com/path_to_your_app/index.php',
        'req_perms' => 'read_stream'
    ));

    //use javascript to redirect. the oauth endpoint cant be loaded in an
    //iframe, so we have to bust out of the iframe and load it in the browser
    //and tell the oauth endpoint to come back to the fb canvas location
    echo "<script>window.top.location='{$loginUrl}';</script>";
    exit;
}

print_r($facebook->api('/me/home'));
print_r($facebook->api('/me/feed'));
```

Comment: This still doesnt helps me @Jim Rubenstein it just redirects me to this link http://www.facebook.com/developers/login_error.php?app_id=113439898741047&connect=1&type=connect and shows nothing there and nothing happens. The code i posted earlier is showing me my friends but it DOES NOT work for any other ID i dont know basics of Facebook Apps,Please help

Comment: whenever i try to run my previous code(written in the orignal question above) from another Facebook account it shows me this error


Fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException: An active access token must be used to query information about the current user. thrown in /home/content/58/6774358/html/test/src/facebook.php on line 560

i dont know why the code i have written first is working for me only@Jim Rubenstein

Comment: cant figure out why it shows me friends for my facebook id and shows this error atal error: Uncaught OAuthException: An active access token must be used to query information about the current user. thrown in /home/content/58/6774358/html/test/src/facebook.php on line 560 for another facebook id@Jim Rubenstein

Comment: @techie_28 - facebook has been having problems with their developer application lately ([facebook.com/developers](http://www.facebook.com/developers)), which is why you get a blank page when you go there.  As for your OAuthException, are you loading your page in the Facebook canvas, or via an external site? (Is your url app.facebook.com/your_app/ or http://your-site.com/your/app)?

Comment: http://apps.facebook.com/test_this_new_app/ this is my app url @Jim Rubenstein and when i click on https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed?access_token=... or https://graph.facebook.com/me/home?access_token=... it shows me the results but not in case of my app. I am trying to accesshttp://apps.facebook.com/test_this_new_app/ this url from one facebook id in mozilla and another facebook id in google chrome and it works for one only and shows me error for the chrome.The facebook id from which i created this app is working fine for the app(i.e showing me my friends not news feeds or likes)